# Xcode script to add type annotation everywhere

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I saw [this post](https://hackernoon.com/speed-up-swift-compile-time-6f62d86f85e6) and I was wondering if there is a possibility to write a script for Xcode for an existing project that will add type annotations in Swift code, like this:

```
let a = 40 -> let a: Int = 40
```

And would do so for all variables and constants in the project. Given that a project can have dozens of thousands (or millions) of these lines, it could speed up compile and/or build time.

Comment: **Don't do that**. Let the compiler infer the type unless it tells you to annotate. Everybody can write anything in the net. There is no proof that type annotations save compile time.

Comment: Why not? If it's inferring types of so many properties it can speed up compile and build type if it doesn't go forward and backward at each line to check the type.

Comment: Especially in case of optionals type annotations are error-prone and it can do more harm than good. I'd prefer to look for optimizing the code rather than the compiler.